# How to override the :hook section of a use-package declaration

Tags: hooks, use-package, doom

I am attempting to change the `:hook` section of a `use-package` declaration that I cannot directly modify. In my case, I want to remove hooks that are getting set, not just add more hooks. Is there a way to do this similar to how the `:init` and `:config` sections can be modified via `use-package-inject-hooks`?

Reference points:

1. The `use-package` library provides a `use-package-inject-hooks` variable that can be enabled in order to activate hooks for the `:init` and `:config` sections:

   ```
   [use-package-inject-hooks]

   If non-nil, add hooks to the `:init' and `:config' sections.
   In particular, for a given package `foo', the following hooks
   become available:

     `use-package--foo--pre-init-hook'
     `use-package--foo--post-init-hook'
     `use-package--foo--pre-config-hook'
     `use-package--foo--post-config-hook'

   This way, you can add to these hooks before evaluation of a
   `use-package` declaration, and exercise some control over what
   happens.

   NOTE: These hooks are run even if the user does not specify an
   `:init' or `:config' block, and they will happen at the regular
   time when initialization and configuration would have been
   performed.

   NOTE: If the `pre-init' hook return a nil value, that block's
   user-supplied configuration is not evaluated, so be certain to
   return t if you only wish to add behavior to what the user had
   specified.
   ```
2. The `:hook` section provides an alternate interface for special-case usage of the `:init` section (see [documentation](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package#hooks)):

   > The `:hook` keyword allows adding functions onto package hooks. Thus, all of the following are equivalent:
   >
   > ```
   > (use-package ace-jump-mode
   >   :hook prog-mode)
   >
   > (use-package ace-jump-mode
   >   :hook (prog-mode . ace-jump-mode))
   >
   > (use-package ace-jump-mode
   >   :commands ace-jump-mode
   >   :init
   >   (add-hook 'prog-mode-hook #'ace-jump-mode))
   > ```

Given the above two points, I thought that maybe hooking into the `:init` section using `use-package-inject-hooks` would allow me to override the `:hook` section, but that was not the case. Looking at the source code for `use-package`, I can see that `:hook` and `:init` are implemented differently (`:hook` is not a special wrapper for `:init`) so I can see why that would not work.

Any advice would be much appreciated. (On that note... I suppose a clever use of the *advice* mechanism in Emacs could provide a workaround, which I hadn't considered until I wrote that last sentence. That said, I would like to avoid such a kludge if possible.)

Comment: If you cannot directly modify the `use-package` declaration, I'm not sure what you mean when you say "hooking into the :init: section"... I don't understand your context, but it sounds like `(advice-remove ...)` called after your `use-package` code would be the simplest solution.

Comment: Context: I am a Doom Emacs user and currently do not have the time to maintain my own fork, which I believe would be necessary in order for me to directly modify the `use-package` form in question.

Comment: Doom's configuration appears to be sufficiently distinct from regular Emacs that you might be better off looking for help from the maintainers directly. https://discord.gg/qvGgnVx

Answer (score 1):

I think something has gone wrong if you can't modify the use-package form -- AFAIK that macro is intended for use by end-users only.

That said, the documentation you've quoted:

> all of the following are equivalent:
>
> ```
> (use-package ace-jump-mode
>   :hook prog-mode)
>
> (use-package ace-jump-mode
>   :hook (prog-mode . ace-jump-mode))
>
> (use-package ace-jump-mode
>   :commands ace-jump-mode
>   :init
>   (add-hook 'prog-mode-hook #'ace-jump-mode))
> ```

suggests to me that you can probably just do the following (subsequent to loading the above code):

```el
(with-eval-after-load 'ace-jump-mode
  (remove-hook 'prog-mode-hook #'ace-jump-mode))
```

Comment: As a Doom Emacs user, I think the trick for me is figuring out exactly when the `use-package` form is evaluated (the lazy loading is probably what's tripping me up). Your code makes sense but for whatever reason it's not working in my case.